# How to unshare DropBox files using DropBox API?

Tags: api, share, dropbox

I already "crawled" the whole Dropbox API and I just cannot find any possibility to UNSHARE files and folders.
There is the feature to generate a link you can share with your friends and colleagues but is there a "unshare option"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked in the dropbox's developer forum and they said that there is no option to unshare files and folders. The user MUST use the dropbox website for that.

Comment: I haven't confirmed with the API yet but there might be a workaround to this. See my comment below:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719017/dropbox-unshare-files#comment36504904_14719209

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about [/shares](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#shares), you are probably stuck moving the file in order to invalidate the given address, and if [/fileops/move](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#fileops-move) doesn't work, perhaps [/fileops/copy](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#fileops-copy) and then [/fileops/delete](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#fileops-delete).

Comment: So I have to copy and delete the file? There is no  possibility to just unshare the file?

Comment: I don't have an API access set up, so I would try moving it first :).

Comment: I tried moving it - didnt work for me

Comment: I didn't use the API for it (that's going to be my next test) but moving the file did not disable the share. I had to copy the file and delete the original for the share to go away. Just to confirm that's: "Copy sharedFile.ext to sharedFile-temp.ext", "Delete sharedFile.ext", "Move sharedFile-temp.ext to sharedFile.ext" (If you want the file back in the same place with the same name which I assume you do). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Just to update, using the API to copy/delete/move a shared file does not "unshare" it. It might work if you have your servers download the file and re-upload it but that's too much bandwidth for what I wanted to do. The best I can come up with is if the user shares from within your app you can copy the file to a folder (ex: "/share") then when they want to "unshare" you just delete that file. But then they have to keep 2 copies of the file which isn't ideal except for quick one-time-shares or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

Open the file using dropbox link generated and sign in to your dropbox account. You will find gear icon at the top of the page. click on the icon and then click remove link. Link to your file will be removed and file is no more shared. Hope this helps.

Comment: Op is asking how to do it via the Dropbox API, not how to do it on their website.